# GoLang net/http memory keeps increasing on contineous requests

Tags: go, http

I have the following code in GoLang

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func httpClient() *http.Client {
    var transport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: false,
}
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 60 * time.Second, Transport: transport}
    return client
}

func sendRequest(client *http.Client, method string) []byte {
    endpoint := "https://httpbin.org/post"
      values := map[string]string{"foo": "baz"}
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(values)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, endpoint, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error Occurred. %+v", err)
    }

    resp, err:= client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        log.Fatalf("Error sending request to API endpoint. %+v", err)
    }

    // Close the connection to reuse it
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't parse response body. %+v", err)
    }   
    return body
}

func main() {
  // c should be re-used for further calls
    c := httpClient()
    for i := 1; i <= 60; i++ {
    response := sendRequest(c, http.MethodPost)
    log.Println("Response Body:", string(response))
    response = nil
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
    }
}
```

When executed, it keeps the memory size increasing and the growth goes to as much as 90mb in one hour. is the gc not working properly. Even though i am using same httpclient for multiple requests but it still looks like theres something thats increasing the size of memory footprint.

Comment: how do you measure memory usage ?

Comment: The go runtime is quite complex. Based on the code you show here, nothing really stands out as a memory leak, but then the code doesn't really look like something that would be running for 1 hour (you're making 60 requests with a 1 second sleep in between, so this should run in 1 minute + request time). All we essentially know is that you claim to see 90MB of memory usage, but no indication as to what means you're using to assess memory usage. Also: `time.Milisecond * 1000` can be abbreviated to `time.Second`

Comment: I am testing the code for 60 seconds obviously for the sake of time saving. Because that timeframe is enough to debug on longer usages. I am obviously running the program in for loop for 3600 in 1hr timeframes.

Comment: @davidriod using sys internals process monitor.

Comment: If using 90M is not causing any memory pressure, and it keeps the garbage collector running smoothly, then there is no problem. The only way to leak memory is via goroutines which are not returning, so a stack trace is the best way see if you actually have a problem. The most concise way to see what the garbage collector is doing (and what memory the process sees as being used) is by viewing the gctrace output.

Comment: @JimB, will definitely do it but i was trying to avoid it as it was a lengthy process for a small problem.

Comment: There is no lengthy process, send a `SIGQUIT` to dump a full stack trace, use `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` to see the gctrace output. In all likelihood you are chasing a nonexistent problem, and memory usage levels out over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use tools like *pprof*, these are very useful at troubleshooting precisely this kind of issues.

You have set `DisableKeepAlives` field to false, which means that it will keep open connections even after the requests have been made, leading to further memory leaks. You should also call `defer resp.Body.Close()` after calling `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`. This is precisely the purpose of the `defer` keyword - preventing memory leaks. GC does not mean absolute memory safety.

Also, outside of main avoid using `log.Fatal`. Use leveled logger, like zap or zerolog instead, since `log.Fatal` calls `os.Exit(1)` with an immediate effect, which means your `defer` statements will take no effect, or call plain `panic`. See [Should a Go package ever use log.Fatal and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885235/should-a-go-package-ever-use-log-fatal-and-when)

Comment: Aside from debugging, the main purpose of this program is to reuse the existing http connection.

Comment: `defer resp.Body.Close()` is called. It's the statement just before the `ioutil.ReadAll()` call. The defer doesn't have to be added _after_ the `ReadAll` call, it's deferred to occur after the function returns, so the response body will be closed regardless

Comment: Got it but doing so has no impact on improvement thus.